# How is this example NOT transitive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

R = {(a,a),(a,b),(b,a),(b,b),(b,c),(c,b),(c,c)}

Relations are seriously driving me insane. I am revising for my exams and I'm so confused on this stuff. I felt like I was getting a grip of it, then I saw this example... please help me.

Comment: $(a,b)$ is there, $(b,c)$ is there, but $(a,c)$ is not there. You should perhaps first review the definition again.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189)
[Please use MathJax.](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189)  For some
basic information about writing math at this site, see
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).
Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189)
for writing a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation is not transitive since $a$ is related to $b$, $b$ is related to $c$ but $a$ is not related to $c$.

Comment: @Jake_Jackson You should study your definitions ! It can be quite hard to prove a property if you don't know what the property means ! The Relation is transitive if  $ \forall a,b,c :aRb, bRc$ implies $aRc$. An example of a transitive relations is "living in the same city "Because if $a$ "lives in the same city as" $b$ and $b$ "lives in the same city as" $c$ then $a$ and $c$ live in the same city. Y

Answer (score 1):

For transitivity you have to check if $x\sim y$ and $y\sim z$ then $x\sim z$.

The relation is given by your set $R$.

And it is $a\sim b$ and $b\sim c$. Is $a\sim c$?

Comment: You mean:  is $a\sim c$?

Comment: I edited it. Thanks.